# How to return a HTTP error code in PHP?

Tags: php, http

I am trying to create a mysql query where it echo out the files from the database. Here, I want the computer to echo out the detail of the file if there is such id number input by user whereas if there is no such id number of the file then it has to echo out HTTP 404 error code.

I have used this code at the top of the page.

```
      <?php
        http_response_code(404);
       ?>
```

The above code says Call to undefined function http_response_code()

And also when I use this code in something like if statement true then echo or if false then http_response code. It doesn't work.

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I guess PHP 4!! How can I check the version of the PHP?

Comment: http_response_code() was added in PHP 5.4, so you're probably on an older version.

Comment: @MarcB, what if I am using PHP 4? Is there any other way to implement this task?

Comment: @SandeshMgr You're probably not on PHP 4, but rather 5.2 or 5.3. You can check by using `phpinfo()` or `php -v` within your ssh shell

Comment: if you're on php4, you really should upgrade. v4 doesn't even qualify as stone age anymore.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using >= php4.0
use :

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

php >= 4.3

```
header(':', true, 404);
```

php >= 5.4

```
http_response_code(404);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use http_response_code(), try this:

```
if (!$results) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    require_once('errors/404.php');
    exit;
}
```

You need to create 'errors/404.php' and add some text there.